# Proof using Baire’s Lemma

Tags: sequences-and-series, banach-spaces, baire-category

Let $E$ be an infinite dimensional Banach space and let $(u_n)_{n\ge1}$ be a
sequence of elements in $E$. Let $F$ be the vector subspace of $E$ consisting of finite
linear combinations of the $u_n$. Prove that we cannot have $F = E$.

Plus: Let $E$ be the Banach space of continuous functions on the compact interval
$[a, b]$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$ with the norm $|| · ||_∞$. Give an example of a sequence $(u_n)_{n \ge 1}$
in $E$ such that the space $F$ defined above has its closure equal to $E$.

I do not know how to start, ideas and suggestions are appreciated, many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $F=E$. Then  $E=\cup_n M_n$ where $M_n=span \{u_1,u_2,..,u_n\}$. Any finite dimensional subspace is closed and a proper subspace has no interior. Hence $M_n$'s are nowhere dense. So Baire's Theorem gives a contradiction.

For the second part consider the class of all polynomials with rational coefficients. This is  a countbale set and we can write it  as a  sequence $(u_1,u_2,...)$. The fact that $F=E$ in this case follows easily from Weierstrass Approximation Theorem.

Comment: Many thanks!, I added a question about an example of equal closure If you have something in mind!

Comment: @duster I have edited my answer.